# Applying Custom Color as background to excel table row using jxl

Tags: excel, colors, background-color, jxl

I have learned how to apply colours to background of excel table row using jxl library by using the below code

```
WritableFont cellFonts = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 11, WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE, jxl.format.Colour.BLACK);
WritableCellFormat cellFormats = new WritableCellFormat(cellFonts);
cellFormats.setBackground(Colour.AQUA);
```

but i dont know how to apply custom color as background

when i tried this `Colour myColour = Colour(221,221,221);` i got exception

```
WritableFont cellFonts = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 11, WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE, jxl.format.Colour.BLACK);
WritableCellFormat cellFormats = new WritableCellFormat(cellFonts);
Colour myColour = Colour(221,221,221);
cellFormats.setBackground(myColour);
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a method:

```
private final WritableCellFormat getCellFormat(Colour colour) throws WriteException {

WritableFont cellFonts = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 11, WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE, jxl.format.Colour.BLACK);
WritableCellFormat cellFormats = new WritableCellFormat(cellFonts);


myColour= new Colour(10000, "1", 221, 221, 221) {
            };

cellFormats.setBackground(myColour);

return cellFormats;
}
```

You need to:
change this:

```
Colour myColour = Colour(221,221,221);
cellFormats.setBackground(myColour);
```

to this:

```
myColour= new Colour(10000, "1", 221, 221, 221) {
            };
```

and set in cell:

```
Label label1 = new Label(column, row, "text of cell or nothing", getCellFormat(myColour));
```

I hope helps.

Comment: Colour(int, String, int, int, int) constructor is protected.

Comment: And nowadays this Constructor/Class is deprecated: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/write/Colour.html